# how to remove more than one space between two words of string in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

`this.folderObj.folderName` is string and I print `console` of that string `aaa         aaa`, I use `trim()` but it removes only before and after white spaces,how to remove more than one space between two words of string and want output like this `aaa aaa`

```
  folderObj : Folder = new Folder();

  console.log(this.folderObj.folderName.trim());  // aaa         aaa
```

expected console that i want

```
console.log(this.folderObj.folderName.trim())  // aaa aaa
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match two or more space characters, and replace with a single space:

```js
const folderName = '    aaa         aaa';
console.log(
  folderName
    .replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ')
    .trim()
);
```

Of course, you could also match one or more space characters instead with `+`, the code will look nicer, but it'll be very slightly less efficient:

```js
const folderName = '    aaa         aaa';
console.log(
  folderName
    .replace(/ +/g, ' ')
    .trim()
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with `replace()` to replace all single and multiple spaces with single space.

```
this.folderObj.folderName.trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ');
```

**Demo:**

```js
console.log('aaa         aaa'.replace(/ +/, ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let folderName = '      abcd       xya   ';
console.log(folderName.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const folderName = "    aaa         aaa";

let resultStr = folderName
  .trim()
  .split(' ')
  .filter(item => item.length > 0)
  .join(' ');

console.log(resultStr);
```